# How to get relative URL path for an image uploaded on Oracle WebCenter

Tags: image, oracle, url, relative-path, webcenter

We are working on a requirement where we have to show a signature image on an RTF Template. This signature changes for one bank to other, so we are thinking to upload them in UCM server and use the URL's relative path concatenated with Bank Account ID/Number to fetch the image into RTF.

But, when we upload image by following Note 1605094.1 we are not able to get a relative path to hard code in our template file.

Uploaded one image (`5486173210.gif`), and the URL generated is as below

```
http://<ucmhost>:<ucmport>/cs/groups/public/documents/digitalmedia/ndg2/mtcz/~edisp/5486173210.gif
```

And the second image (`11223344.gif`) got the URL like below

```
http://<ucmhost>:<ucmport>/cs/groups/public/documents/digitalmedia/mdex/mjiz/~edisp/11223344.gif
```

We are looking for a common relative URL path, so that we can hard code that in our RTF Template.

URL something like below helps us.

```
http://<ucmhost>:<ucmport>/cs/groups/public/documents/digitalmedia/logos/5486173210.gif

http://<ucmhost>:<ucmport>/cs/groups/public/documents/digitalmedia/logos/11223344.gif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the [GET_FILE](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wcc/CSSRG/GUID-5443AA3F-DDE9-4E91-BB41-93651ABE7FFF.htm#CSSRG-GUID-B28C9076-25E7-446F-B49D-F26F9F00183B) service URL?

```
http://<ucmhost>:<ucmport>/cs/idcplg?IdcService=GET_FILE&RevisionSelectionMethod=LatestReleased&allowInterrupt=1&dDocName=
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, tried to fetch one image with the URL reference you provided and it worked! Trying for more images, will keep you posted!!

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it working. I'd recommend always using GET_FILE instead of the other URL you were using (which is prone to break if the metadata changes).